# SQL Server database with two log files

Tags: sql-server

> SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

I have inherited a SQL database that has been configured to use two transaction log files. I'd like to just get rid of one of the log files, because it's really not best practice and just creates additional maintenance requirements. I have pulled a full backup and restored to a test server, and have attempted to just remove the 2nd log file using SSMS.

The "Remove" appeared to work, but when I went back into the database later the 2nd file had reappeared (at 1 MB in size). At this point, I was not able to remove it again at all, recieved an error from SSMS tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at sys.database_files while in the context of the database in question.  Specifically, look at the state_desc and drop_lsn columns.  You may have to back up the database after dropping the file to get it to disappear completely from the system.

Comment: state_desc = OFFLINE and drop_isn = a really long string of numbers. advice?

Comment: Ran a transaction log backup and the file disappeared from the system as I had hoped. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Do a SQL backup of the log file then remove the log file from the database.  The backup you perform will depend on what recover model your database is in.

You can use `ALTER DATABASE` to remove the log file once there is no active data in the log file.

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase
REMOVE FILE MyDataBaseLog
```

Where `MyDataBaseLog` is the logical filename of your log file.

You can get the logical name of your log file by using `sp_helpdb`:

```
sp_helpdb MyDataBase
```

The file information is in the 2nd resultset returned by `sp_helpdb`

Comment: The "sp_helpdb" command showed only one log file. I also checked my SAN partition and the physical file appears to be gone as well. I went ahead and completely rebooted the server, but in SSMS it still thinks I have two log files. What is going on here?